# Who knows Midi hex strings?

Tags: hex, midi, coremidi

I am trying to send a midi Note On message on channel 1 with data C0 127

I can see this info from midi monitor, but need help figuring out how to convert that into a hex string.

This is what the correct string for "stop" looks like : 
Byte  midiDataToSend[] = {0xF0, 0x7F, 0x7F, 0x06, 0x01, 0xF7};

Can someone provide an example for Note On, Channel 1, Data C0 127 so that I can understand how to construct note on  and pitchwheel messages?

Comment: You're saying you want to send the message: Note: 'C0' Velocity: 127 on channel 1 -- yes?

Comment: Take a look at this where it says _note-on examples_ and see if you can work it out: http://www.tonalsoft.com/pub/pitch-bend/pitch.2005-08-31.17-00.aspx

Comment: Hmm -- your "stop" example seems to be a [system exclusive code](http://www.midi.org/techspecs/midimessages.php), not a general MIDI command.

Comment: yeah the stop message is a MMC command using the F0 status type, I'm trying to figure out how to send a regular note on/off message, it would be so helpful to have an example to work from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED** corrected byte values from comments

The note-on message is three bytes:

- Midi Channel
- Key Number
- Velocity

Midi Channel has a fixed value in the first nibble of '1001' or hex digit 9.  The second nibble is the channel number, which in your case is one so the first hex byte should be `90`

The Key or Note Number for 'C0' happens to be hex `0c` 
[Hex-to-Midi Note Chart](http://www.wavosaur.com/download/midi-note-hex.php)

> **UPDATE:** *Octave numbering is not standardized. Therefore, “C4″ on one device may correspond to “C5″ on another.*  The proper value for
>   the OP was hex `18`

The velocity is 127 is hex `7f`

You might also want to be prepared to send a NOTE OFF as well -- the note on message has infinite duration.  ;)

Comment: Thanks david so would this be correct? Just three hex btyes? or do I have to prefix it with something else, doesn't seem to be working for me? {0x91, 0x0c, 0x7f }

Comment: I don't have a setup I can test on.  That should do it.  Can you describe your hardware setup?  I have not done any MIDI for a long time, but you may need to initialize a connection to the hardware before you start sending.  That part may not be standard.  In the past I tended to use libraries to help with the heavy-lifting.

Comment: I think I just caused an `off-by-one` error.  Can you please try hex `90` for the first byte instead of `91` ???

Comment: Thanks yeah I'm using coreMidi. I am already sending MMC commands over a bonjour connection so I know the connection is working.  {0x91, 0x0c, 0x7f } doesn't even show up on midi monitor when I spy on the outout so I'm thinking maybe it needs a status byte in front of it.

Comment: That works thanks! It's sending C-1 127 on channel 1.

Comment: so for some reason it's off by an octave. instead of 0c i tried 18 and it now sends C-0 127. Thanks for your help